# Moving site form typo3 to concrete5

Tags: typo3, concrete5

Is there any other way than copy paste text, to move content from typo3 to concrete5?

Best Regards
Mats Krüger

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, if your typo3 page is simple/big enough, it's possible/worth to write a php script that gets data from typo3's database, manipulates and writes into concrete5's. Database logic seems to be quite different though, so it can be tricky.

Comment: The site is huge.
So it would take days to copy paste the site.

Answer (score 0):

Without any information about the structure you can import into concrete5 it is difficult to answer. But there are some general possibilities to export data from TYPO3.

There is an Extension [l10nmgr](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/l10nmgr) which is desined to output TYPO3 content for translation processes. Perhaps you can use the XML and transform it?

You could just write an TypoScript Template which creates an XML File with tags you need. It should be easy to export the build in content elements with that.

Or just have a look at the database and write an connector as kraabus mentioned.